# Class or enumeration using declaration

Tags: c++, class, enumeration, using, language-lawyer

The beginning of 3.4.3.1/1 of N3797 said:

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the
>   name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the
>   scope of the class (10.2), except for the cases listed below.

and one of this rules is:

> the lookup for a name specified in a using-declaration (7.3.3) also
>   finds class or enumeration names hidden within the same scope
>   (3.3.10).

Can you get an example to demonstrate that rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what the standard provides:

```
struct A {
  struct s {} s;
  enum e { e };
};
struct B: A {
  using A::s;
  using A::e;
};
struct B::s s2;
enum B::e e2;
```

The *using-declaration*s in the scope of `B` bring into scope the class and enumeration names `A::s` and `A::e`, even though they are hidden by a member and enumerator respectively.

Note that the *using-declaration*s also bring into scope the member and enumerator, so the class and enumeration are still hidden within the scope of `B`; this means that to use them within `B` or elsewhere we need to use the `struct` and `enum` tags.

Comment: I don't think this is it, remove `using A::{s,e}` from within `B` and the snippet will still be legal, because of `[class.member.lookup]p5` (stating that the Base is searched if a name isn't introduced in Derived). Or is that the point of the whole section, not making a *using-declaration* forget about the other names in the base?

Answer (score 0):

In the following code `B::m_s` hides `A::m_s` in `C`. But it can be made directly accessible via `using A::m_s`.

To see the difference comment out the using-directive.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string m_s;
    A() :
        m_s("I am A::m_s")
    {}
};

struct B: A {
    std::string m_s;

    B() :
        m_s("I am B::m_s")
    {}
};

struct C: B {
    using A::m_s;


};

int main() {
    C c;
    std::cout << '\n' << c.C::m_s << '\n';
}

/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ -g test.cc -o a.exe && ./a.exe"
    End:
 */
```